# Py2exe Error creating exe - Directory

Tags: python

So I'm just trying to create an exe from a simple hello world program using py2exe. I have created the setup file (setup.py) with the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

(I have also tried setup(console=[{"script":'hello.py'}]) as per another suggestion   )

I run cmd as an administrator and type `C:\python27\setup.py py2exe`

It then says:

`error: hello.py: No such file or directory`

I have the hello.py file in the same folder as the setup file. Looked at many different forums and py2exe tutorials and none seem to have answers, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The file path is correct (i have the setup.py and helo.py saved in the python27 folder)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first navigate to that directory and **then** make the python call:

```
C:>cd C:\python27
C:\python27>python setup.py py2exe
```

Note: your `hello.py` script should also be in `C:\python27` directory.